# List of things that were proposed and rejected for bitcoin but implemented in Monero

Tags: privacy, development, bitcoin

This is a follow-up question based on this answer: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/12600/

> **Many things proposed and rejected for Bitcoin have found a place in Monero (privacy for starters)**. That said, it's worth noting that it was Dandelion, not Dandelion++, that was originally proposed for Bitcoin and there were various objections, most unrelated to possible DoS attack vectors.

What are other things apart from 'Dandelion' that were proposed and rejected for bitcoin but implemented in Monero?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an exhaustive list to hand for you, but a few things that spring to mind: "one-CPU-one-vote" (Satoshi), Confidential Transactions (Maxwell), privacy (many aspects proposed by many people), Schnorr signatures (although it's looking like this will get implemented at some point) and of course Dandelion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature